# prerender.io and using _escaped_fragment_= with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, prerender

I have a site that is using prerender.io. Last year it was all working smoothly. This year I had to change the site and I moved it from a .net project to a pure AngularJs application (using yeo angular).

This was done a couple of months ago. What I have recently found, is that prerender.io is not caching my pages anymore.
I found that my web.config has changed. I added this rule:

```
    <rule name="SEO" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.html|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.woff|\.ttf|\.m4v|\.svg|\.torrent))(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|Facebot|twitterbot|googlebot" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://service.prerender.io/http://www.kudos-sports.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_X_PRERENDER_TOKEN" value="****" />
      </serverVariables>
    </rule>
```

This is now allowing prerender to cache my site, but it doesn't cache it properly.
If you go to https://www.kudos-sports.com/?_escaped_fragment_= and have a look, you can see that it just pulls in the text that is on the index page.
It doesn't load the ui-view contents :(

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you send us an email at support@prerender.io? We'll be happy to help look into this for you!

Answer (score 1):

Google has already deprecated `_escaped_fragment_` support.

Reference:

1. https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html
2. https://medium.com/finnovate-io/googlebot-no-longer-picking-up-content-in-prerender-io-pages-ae21d9710459